# Show, that the product of two simple functions is a simple function

Tags: real-analysis

Honestly, I don't really know what to do here, because, as the simple function is defined as:

$$f = \sum_{j=1}^m a_j \chi_{A_j}$$

I'd be dealing with the product of two such sums, and I don't know how to write this out.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the distributive property to write $fg = \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n [\ldots]$

Comment: Hint: to get a nice closed form expression, consider the common refinement of the sets on which the simple functions are defined. I.e., if the functions are defined on $\{E_i\}_i$ and $\{F_j\}_j$, consider the set $\{E_i \cap F_j\}_{i,j}$.

Comment: Another method: First show that your definition of a simple function $f$ is equivalent to $f$ taking only finitely many values. Then show that for any two simple $f,g$, their product only takes finitely many values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let our simple functions be

$$f = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \chi_{A_i} \qquad g = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \chi_{B_j}$$

We can pad out whichever sum has fewer terms by letting additional $A_i$ or $B_j$ be empty, so without loss of generality let us examine

$$f = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{A_i} \qquad g = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \chi_{B_i}$$

Then taking the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product),

$$fg = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} c_k \text{ wherein } c_k = \sum_{\ell=1}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell} \cdot \chi_{A_\ell} \chi_{B_{k-\ell}}$$

Of course it should be evident that

$$\chi_{A_\ell} (x) \cdot \chi_{B_{k-\ell}}(x)
= \begin{cases}
1 & x \in A_\ell \land x \in B_{k-\ell} \\
0 & x \not \in A_\ell \lor x \not \in B_{k-\ell}
\end{cases}
= \chi_{A_\ell \cap B_{k-\ell}}(x)$$

Hence

$$fg = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \sum_{\ell = 1}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell} \cdot \chi_{A_\ell \cap B_{k-\ell}}$$

clearly itself a simple function.